# How to count Java PrefixAverages algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

there I have these two algorithms that are implemented from Pseudo code. My question is how can I count primitive operations and derive T(n) for both algorithms and also to find out the time complexity of (Big-Oh, O(n)) of each algorithm?

```
public class PrefixAverages1 {

static double array[] = new double[10];

public static void prefixAverages(){

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

    double s = array[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){

            s = s + array[j];
        }

    array[i] = s / (i + 1);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

}
public static double[] prefixAverages(double[] inArray) {
double[] outArray = new double[inArray.length];
return outArray;

}


public static void main(String... args) {
System.out.println(
   Arrays.equals(
      prefixAverages(new double[] {5, 6, 7, 8}),
      new double[] {2, 2.5, 3.5, 4}
   )
);
}
}
```

Prefix2

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PrefixAverages2 {

static double array[] = new double[10];

public static void prefixAverages(){

    double s = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            s = s + array[i];
            array[i] = s / (i + 1);
    }
        array[0] = 10;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static double[] prefixAverages(double[] inArray) {
double[] outArray = new double[inArray.length];
return outArray;

}


 public static void main(String... args) {
 System.out.println(
   Arrays.equals(
      prefixAverages(new double[] {3, 4, 5, 6}),
      new double[] {2, 3.5, 4, 5}
     )
   );
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, primitive operations are considered the sums (or subtraction) and multiplication (or divisions) you have in your code. You can count them from your pseudo-code.

So, this means `s = s + array[j];` this counts as 1 such operation and also does this `array[i] = s / (i + 1);`.

The big O (complexity) is basically the relation you have in your algorithm between the number of elements and the operations required.

In your case for example you have 10 elements (as in `new double[10];` and `i < 10` parts) and require in algorithm 1: 10x(10+1) operations.

This is analyzed as:

- You have an outer loop with 10 runs
- You have an inner loop with also 10 runs (this cannot be different because you cannot get the result differently) meaning the number of outer and inner loop is the same in this algorithm, say `N =10'
- You also have a division inside the outer loop for each run so you have +1 operation here.

So, `10(outer)x( 10(inner)+1(division) ) = 110`

To get complexity, consider that:
If you double the number of elements how does the number of primitive operation is affected?
Let's see:
`Complexity(N) = Nx(N+1)` so `Complexity(2N) = (2N)x((2N)+1) = 4N^2 + 2N`.

But because in complexity what really matters is the biggest degree we get:
`Complexity(2N) ~ 4N^2`. Also the fixed factors before the degree are of no interest we finally get:
`Complexity(2N) ~ N^2` meaning your first algorithm is `O(N^2)`.

You can do the maths for your next algorithm.

P.S. denominator operation does not count as one: `(i + 1)`.

P.S.2 It is not a SO question though as it's not programming one.